# 関数を定義するだけで実行されるものと実行されないものの違い

Tags: swift, uikit

Swiftを参考書を見てプログラミングしていく中で、`func ~`で定義した関数で

普通は

```
func touch(){
    ...
}

touch()
```

のように扱うことは分かりました。

だけれど、

```
func touch(){
    ...
}
```

だけで実行できる関数もあります。
どうして、実行できるのでしょうか？

実行できる関数には、引数に`UI〜`を持つものが多い気がするのですが何か関係しているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

定義するだけで実行されると感じているものは、iOSのつくり上、適切なタイミングで呼ばれるように作られているのです。なので、逆に言うとそういった定義するだけで実行されるように感じるものに関しては、なんとなく定義するのではなく、どういったタイミングで実行されるのかマニュアルなどで確認して、いつ実行されるのか把握する必要があります。

（具体的なメソッド名が提示されておらず、swiftの参考書を見ているということですので、ざっくりとした説明にとどめています）